# Cannot pip install psycopg 3 on EC2 (CentOS)

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, pip, centos

What I'm working with:

- `CentOS Linux 7 (Core)`
- `Python 3.9.10`
- `pip 22.0.3`
- Using `virtualenv` where `pip list` is

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.0.3
setuptools 60.9.3
wheel      0.37.1
```

How I'm trying to install [psycopg](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/install.html) (tried `sudo` and/or `pip3` on each too):

1:

```sh
pip install psycopg[binary]
```

```
Collecting psycopg[binary]
  Using cached psycopg-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (141 kB)
  Using cached psycopg-3.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (142 kB)
  Using cached psycopg-3.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (141 kB)
  Using cached psycopg-3.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (141 kB)
  Using cached psycopg-3.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (141 kB)
  Using cached psycopg-3.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
  Using cached psycopg-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
  Using cached psycopg-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
  Using cached psycopg-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
  Using cached psycopg-3.0-py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install psycopg[binary]==3.0, psycopg[binary]==3.0.1, psycopg[binary]==3.0.2, psycopg[binary]==3.0.3, psycopg[binary]==3.0.4, psycopg[binary]==3.0.5, psycopg[binary]==3.0.6, psycopg[binary]==3.0.7, psycopg[binary]==3.0.8 and psycopg[binary]==3.0.9 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    psycopg[binary] 3.0.9 depends on psycopg-binary==3.0.9; extra == "binary"
    psycopg[binary] 3.0.8 depends on psycopg-binary==3.0.8; extra == "binary"
    psycopg[binary] 3.0.7 depends on psycopg-binary==3.0.7; extra == "binary"
    psycopg[binary] 3.0.6 depends on psycopg-binary==3.0.6; extra == "binary"
    psycopg[binary] 3.0.5 depends on psycopg-binary==3.0.5; extra == "binary"
    psycopg[binary] 3.0.4 depends on psycopg-binary==3.0.4; extra == "binary"
    psycopg[binary] 3.0.3 depends on psycopg-binary==3.0.3; extra == "binary"
    psycopg[binary] 3.0.2 depends on psycopg-binary==3.0.2; extra == "binary"
    psycopg[binary] 3.0.1 depends on psycopg-binary==3.0.1; extra == "binary"
    psycopg[binary] 3.0 depends on psycopg-binary==3.0; extra == "binary"

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

2:

```sh
pip install psycopg[binary]==3.0.8
```

```
Collecting psycopg[binary]==3.0.8
  Using cached psycopg-3.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (142 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg-binary==3.0.8; extra == "binary" (from psycopg[binary]) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg-binary==3.0.8; extra == "binary"
```

3:

```sh
pip install psycopg-binary
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg-binary (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg-binary
```

Running out of options here, any help would be appreciated. It works on my local machine, but not on EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: The code I have is using psycopg3 not psycopg2

Comment: Decided to use psycopg2 instead, strange because 2 doesn't work locally and 3 does, 3 doesn't work on ec2 but 2 does...

Comment: Glad it worked! :)